# JavaScript Array map doesn't work with addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I want to create HTML elements like this

```
<div>
    <span class="u-label"></span>
    <span class="u-title"></span>
    <span class="u-info"></span>
</div>
```

I use javascript code`$('div').append(Array(3).fill($('<span>test</span>')).map((el, index) => el.addClass(['u-label', 'u-title', 'u-info'][index])));`

However,it doesn't work.It only returns `<div><span class="u-label u-title u-info">test</span></div>`

https://jsfiddle.net/paq8tdfL/

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. only `<li>` elements can be children of a `ul`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Sorry, I found my mistake, it should be div, not ul. However it is not the main point.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @Ionut
    <div>
        <span class="u-label"></span>
        <span class="u-title"></span>
        <span class="u-info"></span>
    </div>

Comment: `.fill($('<span>test</span>'))` is only evaluated once, hence you will have an array with 3 references to the same object and not 3 distinct objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This also works:

```js
$('div').append(Array(3).fill().map((el, index) => $('<span>test</span>').addClass(['u-label','u-title','u-info'][index])));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
</div>
```

Your problem is that `$('<span>test</span>')` is added 3 times to the array, it's the same reference. So when you do `.addClass()` and `.append()` you're working on the same `span` element.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the classes in an `array` and looping through the `array` using a `for` loop can be a much cleaner and more readable approach:

```js
var arr = ['u-label', 'u-title', 'u-info'];

for(var i = 0; i< arr.length; i++){
  $('div').append('<span class="' + arr[i] + '">test</span><br />');
}
```

```css
.u-label{
  color: #F00;
}
.u-title{
  color: #1e8c55;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: I know for can works, but I really want to know why map doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul').append(Array.from(new Array(3)).map(x => $('<li>test</li>')).map((el, index)=>el.addClass(['u-label','u-title','u-info'][index])));
```

Comment: Why Array(3) is different from Array.from(new Array(3))?
Is't Array(3) returns array?

Comment: I see one problem: the return of `$('<li>test</li>')` is null. And when using `fill`, then you end up with an array `[null,null,null]` which is fed into map for adding a Css Class.

Comment: with `Array(3)` you only have a pseudo array which is converted into a real array with `Array.from`. Array(3) is something array-like or iterable. `Array(3)` seems to just have a length but no reserved space for all three of them you want to `fill`.

Comment: I think the real problem is that you're adding the same element to the array 3 times, instead of 3 separate elements.

Comment: ah yeah, and when I use the function `x => $('<li>test</li>')` then I create a new ref every iteration.